# If file name prefix is then skip, if not add prefix

Tags: c#, file

I would like to check if file name contains `prefix`, then if yes, *skip* it if does not add `prefix`. So code should:

1. Go through all files in folder
2. Check each files name
3. If file name *starts* with `prefix` (`"Some prefix ...."`)
4. Skip it
5. If file name *does not start* with `prefix` (`"Some prefix ...."`)
6. Add `prefix` (`"Some prefix ...."`) before existing file name

My current code is able to add prefix before file name, but is not able to detect if prefix already exists. How to add that kind of functionality?

**Current code:**

```
string prefix = "Some prefix ";

var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp", "*.pdf");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    string newFileName = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(file), 
       (prefix + Path.GetFileName(file)));

    File.Move(file, newFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *query* with a help of *Linq* (`Where`)

```
using System.Linq;

...

string prefix = "SomePrefix";

...

var filesToMove = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\temp", "*.pdf")
  .Where(item => !Path
     .GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item)
     .StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  .ToArray();

foreach(string file in filesToMove)
  File.Move(
    file, 
    Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), prefix + Path.GetFileName(file)));
```